# Better CTAs for 'Save & exit' and 'Save & done'?

Tags: forms, cta

I've got a bit of a language block for the final stage of a form-filling journey where the user can either

1. Save what they've done, quit and return later
2. Save what they've done and lock it so no further changes can be made.

**Save and exit** kinda works for 1., but I can't come up with a suitable unambiguously different label for 2.

**Send** is the closest, but no sending is involved – this is simply marking the work as 'complete' and putting it in a read-only state.

**Save & exit** and **Save & done** aren't sufficiently different to me – anyone got anything better..?

Comment: Why not simply use the word "complete"? Most people understand that as the end of their involvement in a process.

Comment: While this is a valid UX question, I feel like the folks over at https://english.stackexchange.com/ could also be of help here

Comment: Yeah, probably, but I just wondered if I was overlooking an existing solution to this. **Save** and **Submit** (below) kinda work, but **Save** also closes the form and so it doesn't tell the whole story (I didn't design the journey – I'm just adding the copy).

Comment: I think the problem comes because if the form is at a state where it can be submitted, then you have 2 options: *send* (and obviously no changes can be made) or *go back and edit* . Obviously, I don´t know your user case, but I can't think of any scenario where an user gets to the end of a survey and she doesn't submit it and saves the form for later use instead.

Comment: This form is for someone to complete with a customer over the phone – and they may need to pause the form-filling while the customer goes away to get the info they need. So this won't always be a single start-to-finish process, but one that could span a few days (it's in finance).

Answer (score 1):

What about "save draft" vs "finalize"/"submit”?

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the end result of filling out the form is. Action A results in the form being inserted/saved/stored in the database, action B results in the form being inserted/saved/stored in the database, but also locked for further editing. How is this clear for me as a user? Simple:

1. Save
2. Submit

A message confirming my action might give me more details: e.g. are you sure you want to submit - no more modifications possible.

Comment: The word "submit" is one that should probably be avoided. It's short and not clear. More details on why: https://uxmovement.com/forms/why-your-form-buttons-should-never-say-submit/